# Cannot pass down history prop to Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to pass down the `history` prop down from the `App` to the Navigation component.
When I try to do so, I get the following error message:

Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Navigation`, but its value is `undefined`.

How can I resolve this issue?

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = props => (
  <Router>
      <MainLayout {...props}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact name="index" path="/" component={Index}/>
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
      </MainLayout>
  </Router>
);
```

MainLayout.js:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Navigation from "../../components/Navigation/Navigation";

const MainLayout = props => {
  const { children, authenticated, history } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation authenticated={authenticated} history={history} />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

MainLayout.PropTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default MainLayout;
```

Comment: Does `history` have a value inside of `MainLayout`? Your error suggests that it is `undefined` by the time `Navigation` is getting it. It also seems that `App` is receiving the `history` prop. Try tracking that prop and ensure that it is defined before it gets passed down.

Comment: The value of `history` inside `MainLayout` is `undefined `, but inside `App` it is assigned a value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION #1:**

If you simply convert `<MainLayout />` to a `<Route />` that renders  you will have access to the history object.

```
<Route render={(props) => 
  <MainLayout {...props}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact name="index" path="/" component={Index}/>
      <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
  </MainLayout>
}/>
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js

`<App />` does not have access to history as a prop so this will never do what you are wanting `<MainLayout {...props}>`

**SOLUTION #2**

You can also reference the history object as a single exported module in your app and refer to that both React router and any other compopent / javascript file in your app.

```
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

const App = props => (
  <Router history={history}>
      <MainLayout history={history} {...props}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact name="index" path="/" component={Index}/>
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
      </MainLayout>
  </Router>
);
```

(history.js)

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

Comment: First of all, thanks :) Unfortunately now I am running into the issue, that when I am calling `onClick={() => history.push("/")}` on an element, I get `Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function`. Any idea how I can resolve that? :)

Comment: My edit should address the problem you mention in this comment

Answer (score 4):

**For react-router-dom v4**

In order to get Router component's prop I used the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter), I guess the below change should work,

```
export default wihtRouter(MainLayout);
```

This should enable the usage of props.history in MainLayout